# Using $compile on external template (templateURL) in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, external

I've got a recursive Angular directive that uses a template variable and gets compiled in the `link` function.

Problem is, that my template has gotten really long and out of control and I want to externalize it in an external HTML file (it would also make it easier for example to auto-indent).

How can you load an external template into a directive that can be used inside the `$compile`?

I've seen `templateURL`, but that doesn't let me name the variable and pass it to the `$compile` function.

```
var template = 
           "<p>My template</p>"+
           "<this-directive val='pass-value'></this-directive>";

return {
     scope: {
     ...
     },
     ...
     link: function(scope, element){
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
}
```

and

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the `$templateRequest` service to get the template. This is a convenience service that also caches the template in `$templateCache`, so that only a single request to `template.html` is made.

As an illustration (and without going into the issue of recursive directives), this is used like so:

```
link: function(scope, element){
   $templateRequest("template.html").then(function(html){
      var template = angular.element(html);
      element.append(template);
      $compile(template)(scope);
   });
};
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P4hPQSXC9xnGfhbIsLNt?p=preview) (check the network tab to see a single network request)

Comment: This is awesome! You are my hero! Can I buy you a coffee?

Comment: I'm curious, is it possible to use html binding (ng-bind-html) inside the "template.html" in your illustration? I can't make it work.

Comment: @zhekaus, yes, but it you still need to use the usual `ngSanitize`/`$sanitize` or otherwise use `$sce.trustAsHtml`

Comment: Do you know why this appears to uncompile whenever it is converted to a string or console logged?

Comment: Just curious is there is a way to maintain two way binding for the template.html

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use $http to load template if its size is bigger:-

```
$http.get('mytemp.html').then(function(response) {
            element.html(response.data);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
```

Comment: You should cache the templates that you load, like this `$http.get('mytem.html', {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(response) {
            element.html(response.data);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
})`

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in the code but I can't edit because it's less than 6 chars :)

Comment: _"The $templateRequest service runs security checks then downloads the provided template using $http and, upon success, stores the contents inside of $templateCache."_ [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest)

So `$templateCache` uses `$http` performing additional operations in one line. The only difference I see is that the template is not put into `$templateCache`, was it the purpose of your code?