# Passing an Angular expression to a custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive:

```
    gymApp.directive('ngListar', function() { 
      return { 
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
          console.log(attr.type);
          return 'js/directives/listar-'+attr.type+'.html';
        }
      }; 
    });
```

The idea is that when I call the directive a parameter is added that will determine which html file to call, so the html looks like this

```
    <tr ng-listar type="{{list.tipo}}"></tr>
```

But the log prints out {{list.tipo}} instead of the value inside of it. Is there a way I can pass the expression as a parameter?

Comment: Have you tried `<tr ng-listar type="list.tipo"></tr>`? That is, without the braces.

Comment: Without the braces the console log just brings: list.tipo without the braces.

Comment: Please avoid using `ng-` as prefix as that is reserved for AngularJS built-in directives. Also avoid using `type` as a custom attribute as the browser already uses that attribute name.

Comment: Use the `ng-include` directive, see [AngularJS ng-include Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is described in the docs for the [`templateUrl`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-) (emphasis mine):

> Because template loading is asynchronous the **compiler will suspend
>   compilation of directives on that element** for later when the template
>   has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and
>   link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not
>   contained any directives.

The variable binding that Angular does is a directive and therefore won't complete until after your directive is done loading its template.

As for a work-around, you might need to manually call `$compile` yourself instead of relying on `templateUrl` to do it for you. See the second note under [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-) for that.

Borrowing some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28863961/1078110), you can do the following in your directive if you use `$templateRequest`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr){
   $templateRequest('js/directives/listar-' + attr.type + '.html').then(function(html){
      var template = angular.element(html);
      element.append(template);
      $compile(template)(scope);
   });
};
```

`$templateCache` and `$http.get` should also be options with very similar code to the above. That should get around the issue of the value not being interpolated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting in attr, Print your scope variable.

```
app.directive("insertAfter", function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            content: "@",
            type: "@"
        }, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log(scope.type);
            element.after(scope.content);
        }
    }
  });
```