# Working with $compile in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile

I am really confused with **$compile** in angularjs.
can anyone help me, What use of $compile in angularjs with an example 
other then in this documentation.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$compile just compile the text to html..

Here is sample example

```js
 angular
                .module("myModule", [])
                .controller("myController", ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
                    $scope.txt = "<b>SampleTxt</b>";
                    $scope.submit = function () {
                        var html = $compile($scope.txt)($scope);
                        angular.element(document.getElementById("display")).append(html);
                    }
                }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myModule" >
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <textarea ng-model="txt" ></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="submit()" />
        <div id="display"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What if i have text in textbox like <b>{{SampleTxt}}</b>. I mean with curly braces. How can I see the value with curly brace in UI after $compile.

Comment: Is it possible to invoke `$compile` service from JavaScript from outside AngularJS as a normal function? I can access the scope using `angular.element()` but how I can access the `$compile` service to create HTML element, compile it and insert it or replace the existing one after modifying it?

Answer (score -6):

The first line of this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile already said all about $compile

in simple word it will compile html dom so that it will use for scope of angular js.

Comment: Any sample example..other then in this documentation.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854303/using-compile-on-external-template-templateurl-in-angular-directive