# Add an action button to DataTables column header in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am trying to add a button to the heading of a column in angular-datatables, which when clicked will run a function. I have tried doing something like this.

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle(function() {
    return '<span>Name</span><button ng-click="runme()">Click me</button>'
})
```

In the same controller, `runme()` function is defined as:

```
$scope.runme = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

But this is not triggered, it only sort the column data, no matter where i clicked on entire header section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using this approach you'll need to `$compile` the content of the `<thead>` (and anything else injected by DataTables you would like AngularJS to be aware of).

A good place to invoke `$compile` is in the `initComplete` callback :

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('initComplete', function() {
      $compile(angular.element('thead').contents())($scope)
   })
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/D72WPqkE3g2UgJTg**

Remember to inject `$compile` to your controller, see for example [**Working with $compile in angularjs**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100061/1407478). (Lousy google does not even bother to fix the errors in their docs, so https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile does not work).

Note: You could also go with static `<table>` markup

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Name</span><button ng-click="runme()">Click me</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Then AngularJS will connect `$scope.runme` to the `ng-click`, and only if you need additional bindings in the dynamic content inserted by DataTables, a `$compile` is needed.